# unit test the javascript functions in my django application

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, mocha.js, chai

I have a Django app, which contains backend logic in `views.py` and front end logic/user data processing written in javascript and jQuery inside HTML files. Now I wanted to write unit tests, can I use mocha-chai for doing this or any other alternative to do unit testing a JavaScript code in Django.

my directory structure

```
myapp
--->templates
----->base.html
----->home.html
```

base.html contains:

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>WElcome</h1>
<script>
function myfunc(){
console.log("welcome")
//some user logic 
}
</sctipt>
```

which framework to use in order to do write a unit test case for this 'myfunc' inside the Django template

Comment: This has nothing to do with Django. Search for unit test frameworks for javascript and you'll find a few, as you found mocha and chai.

Comment: @dirkgroten thank you, i will better go with mocha and chai

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/writing-code/javascript/#javascript-tests
i think this will be useful

Answer (score 2):

We have tried the following:

1. Use the Django testing framework as base
2. extend it to use Nightwatch with a headless browser to run JS
3. use Selenium for integration tests

We failed, however, to get it to work completely because the headless browser did not run all of our JS code. This was some years ago, and the libraries surely have evolved since then.

If you are happy with integration tests only:

Setup the selenium with Django LiveServerTestCase and a headless browser that runs all of your JS code correctly.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/testing/tools/#liveservertestcase

Comment: thank you, but selenium is used for integration testing i wanted to do a unit test for my application

Comment: If you need the Django server to run to be able to run the JS tests, it's not a unit test anymore. Django will create a test DB, and the setup is then an integration test - even if the tests themselves do only "unit testing".